# Using custom font inside UserControl is making my font bold

Tags: ios, forms, xamarin, xamarin.forms, fonts

When I use my fonts outside of user controls I have them loading correctly. But when the word has accent and is inside UserControl the font is appearing in bold, I've tested more than one font and the problem happens.

[image]

In the image I inserted a sentence written on top of the whole frame in the same way as a sentence written inside a UserControl, what is outside proves that the accents work without being bold and inside shows that all the words that are accented are in bold.

The problem only happens on iOS.

Comment: I'd suggest submitting a test case to the XF github

Comment: @Jason can you help me how to do this? Which link should I make and what good practices to do?

Comment: there is a template to follow - https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Comment: @Jason thanks man!

Comment: @Jason I just created a project and inserted the source and created a UserControl and the problem did not happen, there must be something in my code, but I have no idea what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had edited some texts in another editor (VSCode) and also copied some others from another platform that we used, the problem happened due to the encode of these other tools, when pasting in VStudio it caused the problem.

Just rewriting the texts directly by VStudio and the problem has been fixed.

Comment: you may mark your answer as a solution,then it will help others